# Object doesn't support error

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting the object doesn't support error (438) on the following line

```
Sam.dSheet.Copy after:=whatever.Sheets(whatever.Sheets.Count)
```

of this macro. I could not find a solution as the macro runs up to that point (which is almost to the end) Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub SamCopier()

Dim Sam As Workbook, whatever As Workbook
Dim dSheet As Worksheet, fsheet As Worksheet

Set whatever = ActiveWorkbook
Set Sam = ThisWorkbook

Set dSheet = Sam.Worksheets("DataSheet")
Set fsheet = Sam.Worksheets("2015")

MsgBox whatever.Name
MsgBox Sam.Name

If whatever.Name <> Sam.Name Then
    Sam.dSheet.Copy after:=whatever.Sheets(whatever.Sheets.Count)
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: It's just `dSheet.Copy` not `SAM.dSheet.Copy`

Comment: Thank you Rory. That answered the question!